# Killing forked child process along with parent?

Tags: c, child-process, kill

I'm executing a shell script from C with basic unix commands:

```
int pid=fork();
if (0>pid) {} //error
else if (0==pid) //child {
  execv(...);
}
else { //parent
  int status;
  waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
}
```

This works as intended but I wanted to create a watchdog to prevent an executed process running for too much time:

```
kill(pid, SIGTERM);
```

This also works fine, but if the script has children, they become orphan processes.

Let's consider this script:

```
echo 's' | nc a.b.c.d p
```

When `nc` (and the whole script also) hangs and I'm trying to kill it from code, the script will terminate, but `nc` will become orphan and will stay there forever.

In bash, I can use `kill %n` to terminate a process along with its children. What is the way for doing the same in C?

I can also use `pkill -TERM -P parent_pid`. I'm seeking for the same with C/C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this would be to make the program register the child's pids in an array, then when you want to kill them all just send a signal to the parent. The signal handler would go through the array and kill all the childs and then kill itself. It is important to have a handler for when a child has terminated so that when you try to kill all children you don't kill a proccess who has the same pid that that child had before.

Comment: I believe this is not suitable for me: how can I retrieve the pid of `nc` in the current example?